# How can i access vault in SmartContract?

Tags: corda

How can I access vault in Smart Contract?

I want to do below business validation in Smart Contract
- New Data and attachment which I have entered, already exists in vault or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the vault, or any other source of outside information, from within the contract. This is because contract execution must be *deterministic*. If a contract's view of the validity of a ledger update depended on the current contents of your vault, disagreements could arise between different nodes (or even within the same node at different points in time) on whether a given ledger update was valid. This would destroy the integrity of the ledger - there would be no consensus on which updates were valid.

In your case, it might be best to impose the additional constraints you want to impose within the flow. For example, within the flow you could check the contents of the proposed transaction against the contents of the vault, and sign or not sign the transaction accordingly.

It's important to keep in mind - just because a transaction is contractually valid, does not mean you have to sign it!